# Replace Stripbrackets on RegEx Replace

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, replace, brackets

I have an input string with brackets: "[3][4] at [5]"

And this is my sample datatable result of an sql query:

[image]

What I need to do is replace the [i] corresponding the cell in i column.
The output should be:

[3][4] at [5] = "15A Circuit Breaker #348901836 at 19-Afalcon St. Capitol Subdivision"

This is my code:

```
         Dim colstring As String
         Dim arg As String
         Dim remarks As String = "[3][4] at [5]" *this is from a textbox

        While Not i > dtresults.Columns.Count - 1
            rep = "[" & i & "]"

            colstring = dtresults.Columns(i).ColumnName
            arg = Regex.Replace(remarks, rep, colstring, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
            remarks = arg
            i = i + 1
        End While
```

The problem is the output contains the stripbrackets:  "[15A Circuit Breaker] [#348901836] at [19-Afalcon St. Capitol Subdivision]"

How do I explicitly replace a string that contains stripbracket  using Regex.Replace method?

Comment: I think you want to parse that string rather than strip out stuff.  `"[3][4] at [5]"` would become `"34 at 5"` which might work but becomes brittle if there are ever more than 9 columns.  They also help you know how many tokens there are

Comment: the problem is when the user input a number that is strictly a string. for instance: "Customer 1 ordered [3][4] at [5]". it will also replace "1" even though it is strictly a character and not referred to a column index number.

Comment: Why do you have to use regexs, can't you call String.Replace()?

Comment: that actually works, but with Regex, I can call options like, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase (which is very useful to me when I opt to insert it to the database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you want the value in the column of a particular row of a table, then you cannot write the Column name as replacement string like

```
colstring = dtresults.Columns(i).ColumnName
```

instead use

```
colstring = dtresults.Rows(0).Item(i).ToString
```

Add "\" in the replacement string pattern at the beginning like shown below:

```
rep = "\[" & i & "]"
```

Hence your final code will be like this:

```
     Dim colstring As String
     Dim arg As String
     Dim remarks As String = "[3][4] at [5]" *this is from a textbox

    While Not i > dtresults.Columns.Count - 1
        rep = "\[" & i & "]"

        colstring = dtresults.Rows(0).Item(i).ToString
        arg = Regex.Replace(remarks, rep, colstring, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
        remarks = arg
        i = i + 1
    End While
```